# Is it possible to Show Text instead of ID using SELECT * from TableName

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as given below:

#### person_detail

```
id     name    role_id
---------------------------
1      Hamdan    1
2      Sara      2
3      John      2
```

#### tbl_user_roles

```
id     role
---------------
1      Admin
2      Author
```

#### Result I need:

```
id     name    user_role
---------------------------
1      Hamdan    Admin
2      Sara      Author
3      John      Author
```

> Note: **is it possible?** to use on [Select * from tblPerson] statement, because I do not want to type each field name like:
>   I have these Two(2) solutions, but I want to use SELECT statement only.

#### Solution 1

```
SELECT p.id, p.person_name, roles.role
FROM person_detail p
INNER join user_roles roles
ON p.role_id = roles.id
```

#### Solution 2

```
SELECT p.id,
p.person_name,
(SELECT user_roles.role FROM dbo.user_roles WHERE id = p.role_id) As 'user_role' 
FROM dbo.person_detail p
```

#### ::Both works fine, but I don't want ti use above two solutions

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the standard solution?

Comment: Solution 1 is *the* standard way of writing such a query. If you don't want to use it, you ought to explain very carefully *why* it's not appropriate for you.

Comment: You can use **View** in this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is another solution without `JOIN` keyword**

**Example 1:**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `person_detail`,
  `tbl_user_roles`
WHERE
  person_detail.role_id = tbl_user_roles.id
```

> **Note :** Above query will return all columns from both tables

**Example 2:**

```
SELECT
  person_detail.id,person_detail.name,tbl_user_roles.role AS user_role
FROM
  `person_detail`,
  `tbl_user_roles`
WHERE
  person_detail.role_id = tbl_user_roles.id
```

> **Note :** Above query will return selected columns from both tables

**Important Note :** But you shouldn't use this type of query. You should Use `JOIN` keyword when manipulate data with multiple tables

Comment: You're still joining here. All you've done is remove the `inner join` and replaced it with the older style of joins using commas. Generally seen as a [bad thing](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) because it mixes join criteria and filter criteria and it's easy to omit the join criteria. This answer is explicitly encouraging a behaviour that most *professionals* would be trying to *discourage* in others.

Comment: But he wanted to use without JOIN keyword. This is the reason I posted this kinds of answer. Thank you. I will add note in this question to escape this type of styles. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: I don't see the OP expressed anywhere that they were specifically trying to avoid the `JOIN` keyword. Indeed, Solution 2 in their question does not use `join` and it was apparently not acceptable.

Comment: haha, a great answer to fool the OP with his pointless whim :))) Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following, but using the asterix is a bad pratice, unless it's for testing purposes.

```
SELECT p.*, roles.role
FROM person_detail p
INNER join user_roles roles
ON p.role_id = roles.id
```

Comment: You give me one more way of using Asterisk (*), i.e. table-alias.*
Bundle of thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [view](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx) of what you want to see:

```
CREATE VIEW view_user_roles AS
SELECT p.id, p.person_name, roles.role
FROM person_detail p
INNER join user_roles roles
ON p.role_id = roles.id
```

and then select from the view:

```
select * from view_user_roles
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me the use of View, it will also help me in many situations.